# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter

hello i am trying my flutter app 
and i am getting this 
......
Launching lib\main.dart on C6603 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar
  >   Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.5.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.5.0/builder-model-3.5.0.jar
  >   Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.5.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.5.0/apkzlib-3.5.0.jar
  >   Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.5.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.5.0/apksig-3.5.0.jar
  >   Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.5.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.5.0/annotations-26.5.0.jar
  >   Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.5.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.5.0/databinding-common-3.5.0.jar
  >   Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.5.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.5.0/baseLibrary-3.5.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
.....
what is the problem

Comment: can you solve this?